# Debug AngularJS and NodeJS in Webstorm At Once (Without CORS)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, webstorm

I have a client/server app running on NodeJS with an AngularJS frontend. I want to use the built in debugging features of Webstorm, but it just won't work.

Imagine following scenario:

I have a webstorm project with a client folder and a server folder. I can start the debuggers for the client and the server, and it works. But both sessions are on different ports. So an AJAX request to the server inside the client doesn't work without using CORS and telling AngularJS to use a different server address.

In the production version the client will be published under the server, but for developing there is no need to do this.

Does anyone know how achieve this? Something like: The system should behave like one server, under one URL.

Or is my approach stupid?

Best regards,
Kersten

Comment: sorry, haven't got what you mean... Why client and server are on different ports? Isn't your client code served by your server?